# Power Query: How to combine rows of text into one row/column (cell) using a semi colon delimitator

Tags: powerquery

This is my Power query code:

```
let
Source = #"New Project List",
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Project"}),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Project", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Cleaned Text",{{"Project", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Project", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"),
#"Combined Text" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Project"}, ";", "Combined")
in
    #"Combined Text"
```

---

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value ";" to type Function.
Details:
    Value=;
    Type=[Type]
```

Comment: Try replacing it with a combiner function, as is called for in the documentation. eg: `Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None)`

Comment: You  are trying to combine rows or columns?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the code has not transformed the existing single column of text (1000+ rows) into a single cell with all the text separated by a ;. It has just duplicated the text in the Project column into a new column named "Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter". I'm new to PQ so maybe I have misunderstood your code.  My code is now:
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows1"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Project"}, {{"Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter", each Text.Combine([Project], ";"), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

Comment: Your code and the error about which you posted has to do with combining ***columns***.  Now you write you want to combine 1000 cells in a ***single*** column into a ***single*** cell. What are you trying to do? Where are you writing the result? How many characters are there in your 1,000 rows? If more than about 31,000 characters, it won't go into an Excel cell (32,767 including the semicolons). Please post sample data and expected result. BTW, the code in your comment is not what I suggested you use.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I apologise for the confusion.  The question I posted was “How to combine rows of text into one row/column (cell) using a semi colon delimiter.
The following is an example (each month I will have up to 2000 rows all in one column)

Project
230101.0019
230101.0020
230101.0022
230101.0025

The result I want is all the numbers (text format) in one row/column (cell) separated by a semi-colon:

230101.0019; 230101.0020; 230101.0022; 230101.0025;

Comment: If Ron solved your issue, you should mark his answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. You should be able to adapt to your actual situation.

Here is an example of how to combine everything in a single column into a single cell of semicolon delimited values

The code assumes the values in the original `Project` column are numbers and not text strings. If they should be text strings, obviously you won't need to convert them as I do in the second step.

***Sample Column***
[image]

```
let

//create test column
    Source = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(230101.0019,2000,0.0001)}, type table[Project=number]),

//Convert Column of numbers to text
    #"Convert to Text" = List.Transform(Source[Project], each Number.ToText(_,"0.0000")),

//combine column into a single cell
    #"One Cell" = Table.FromColumns({{Text.Combine(#"Convert to Text",";")}}, type table[Project=text])
in
    #"One Cell"
```

***Results***
[image]

If your values in `Project` column are text string, here is an example which creates a column of the project numbers as text strings, and then joins them into a single cell:

```
let

//create test column
// of numbers as text strings
    Source = Table.FromColumns({List.Transform(List.Numbers(230101.0019,2000,0.0001), each Number.ToText(_,"0000"))}, type table[Project=text]),

//combine column into a single cell
    #"One Cell" = Table.FromColumns({{Text.Combine(Source[Project],";")}}, type table[Project=text])
in
    #"One Cell"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ron for your guidance and patience with helping to solve this  Power Query Code.  Here is my final code: 
   
    #"One Cell" = Table.FromRecords({[Project=Text.Combine(#"Removed Duplicates"[#"Details#(lf)Project"], "; ")]})
in
    #"One Cell"